# What is the asymptotic dynamics of the winning position in this game?

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems

$n$ players indexed $1,2,...,n$ play a game of mock duel. The rules are simple: starting from player $1$, each player takes turns to act in the order $1,2,...,n,1,2,...$. In his turn, a player randomly chooses one of the other remaining players as target, and fires one shot at him. If hit, the target is removed from the game. Whoever survives to the last is the winner. All players have the same marksmanship $0\lt p\le 1$, meaning that their shots hit target with probability $p$.

An example: if $p=1$ and $n=3$, player $1$ randomly chooses $2$ or $3$ as his target and fires one shot. The survivor of $1$'s shot will shoot next and fire at the only other remaining player, player $1$. Hence in this case the three players have winning probabilities $0,0.5,0.5$ respectively.

**Question**: which player has the highest winning probability for large $n$'s?

To be more specific, let's define $B(n)$ to be the player with the highest winning probability for the $n$-players game. Are there any regularity about where $B(n)$ tends to occur in $(1,2,...,n)$? In particular:

1. Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} B(n)/n$ exist for any $p$?
2. Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} B(n)=1$ if $p$ is sufficiently small?

**Edit:** Clarified the rules to address possible ambiguity suggested in the comments.

---

If my calculation is correct, the winning probability for player $k$ in the $n$ players game, $s(n,k)$, is given by the recursive formula:

$$
\begin{align}
& s(n,1)=(1-p)s(n,n)+ps(n-1,n-1)\\
& s(n,2)=(1-p)s(n,1)+\frac{n-2}{n-1}ps(n-1,1)\\
& s(n,k)=(1-p)s(n,k-1)+\frac{n-k}{n-1}ps(n-1,k-1)+\frac{k-2}{n-1}ps(n-1,k-2)
\end{align}
$$
for $k\gt 2$.

For large $n$'s and $p=1$, plotting $s(n,k)$ against $k$ looks like sinusoid:

[image]

If you plot the peaks of these curves (i.e. $B(n)$) against $n$, you get this:

[image]

At first glance it seems $B(n)$ just oscillates between $1$ and $n$ in a self-similar fashion. But actually the hill tips wear off further and further away from the diagonal line as $n$ increases and the valleys also grow flatter:

[image]

One can wonder whether the hills will eventually fall to small bumps or be flattened relative to the diagonal line, meaning that $\lim_{n \to \infty} B(n)/n=0$.

On the other hand, $B(n)=1$ becomes more often as $p$ gets smaller. Blue curves are $B(n)$ for $p=0.5,0.48,0.46$ respectively, for $n$ up to 5000 (larger $n$'s take exponentially more time to compute):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can we claim that  $\lim_{n \to \infty} B(n)=1$ for small $p$? Or is there always exceptions?

Comment: Do the players decide who they fire at, or is that also random? Assuming they decide, then the question isn't necessarily well-formed yet, as there could be multiple Nash equilibria (intuitively the first player has an advantage, but the other players could gang up on that player, etc).

Comment: @SeanEberhard There's no communication. The rule states that "each player takes turns to fire one shot randomly at one of the remaining opponents". You can check this is also an equilibrium. It's a very symmetric one. There's absolutely no reason for others to gang up against the 1st one, since they all have the same marksmanship and the situation is symmetric.

Comment: Related to https://oeis.org/A071818

Comment: @Eric you didn't answer sean's question. they can choose to fire at someone without needing to previously communicate.... Also, can you tell me how the situation is symmetric? The first person goes first

Comment: @mathworker21 I answered him by saying that the rule states "each player takes turns to fire one shot randomly at one of the remaining opponents", period. If you insist on looking at the game from a game theory point of view, all I can say is that this rule happens to be consistent with the equilibrium in which everyone fire one shot randomly at one of his opponents in his turn. This equilibrium is symmetric in the sense that each person has the same strategy (randomly firing one shot at his opponents).

Comment: @Eric I think there's ambiguity regarding "fire one shot randomly". Does it imply that the target is chosen (uniformly?) at random, that the shot has a chance of missing, or both?

Comment: I suggest the OP explain carefully in an appendix to the question what game this strategy is a Nash equilibrium for, since everyone is clearly interested. But it does seem to be just a distraction, and this is really about a zero player game.

Comment: The rule is not clear to me either. I gather from the description (I didn't peruse the formulas) that a target is chosen uniformly at random among the living, and you kill them with probability $p$. But it seems $B(n)$ could depend on $p$.

Comment: @IlkkaTörmä I see your point. I've edited the rule to address this point. And I also added an example to clarify. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @VilleSalo You understood the rule correctly. I edited the rule to address this and also added an example to clarify. All players adopting the strategy "randomly choose one other player to shoot in my turn" is a Nash equilibrium for a game where the rule is changed to allow players to freely choose their target.

Comment: @Eric: Ok, I do not see that without a proof and it seems very doubtful to me (why not shoot $B(n)$ instead?), but it is beside the point.

Comment: @VilleSalo Let's consider $n$ players game and it's your turn to shoot. If all other players are adopting the "random shooting" strategy, killing anyone would give you the same winning probability. Because anyone you kill, you always become the last to shoot in a $n-1$ players game.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.

Comment: I agree, after thinking about it for more than 1 minute, it's clear that this question is not at all about a game. But you made that kind of hard on your reader by saying "game" in the title, first line of the question, etc.

Comment: @Eric: I don't understand your recursion formula. For $p = 1$ we get $s(n,1) = s(n-1,n-1)$. Do you have an explanation? Why not $s(n-1,k)$ or some mixture of these values?

Comment: @DieterKadelka p=1 means player 1 will remove his target **for certain**. Whoever his target happens to be, after that target is removed, there're now n-1 players and he becomes the last one of them to shoot.

Comment: I think an interesting question is whether, with $p=1$, you have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\min s(n,k)}{\max s(n,k)} = 1$ or not